# CNN AlexNet algorithm complexity

Tags: math, matrix, neural-network, convolution

I'm first year student in machine learning and I really recently started to immersing.

So, professor gave me a task, **calculate number of**:

- matrix additions
- matrix multiplications
- matrix divisions

Which are processed in the well known convolutional neural network - [AlexNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlexNet).

I found some [matherials](http://vision.stanford.edu/teaching/cs231b_spring1415/slides/alexnet_tugce_kyunghee.pdf) about it, but I really confused where to start.

So, the overall structure might looks like:

[image: AlexNet structure overview]

But, how can I calculate operations for each type distinctly?

Comment: You are asking us to solve do your "work". You should try, and tell us what yu did so we can help you out fixing one problem, not just do the work for you.

Comment: @rakwaht did you read my question? if so do it again. I'm asking about CONCEPT, how matrix manipulation can be calculated DISTINCTLY and on what steps. Instead of placing useless negative vote give some advises about the topic. Otherwise it puts on thought that you no knowledge about and just want to "moderate".

Comment: Yep I read it and yes I was just moderating, btw I ended up here because I thought the question was interesting from the title. Anyway I still think you are seeking a very broad help. You should try with a more specific question, ps don't be upset s nothing personal.

Answer (score 0):

It's a convolutional network. These limit parameters to make the calculations manageable while still giving good results.

This particular network is described in many places and papers, so it's not difficult to get the figures for the number of parameters and conv nets involved.

But you need to start with an understanding of how a convolutional network works. I find this is a good place to start: http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/